# How to use greeting "Moin."

Tags: meaning

I recently came to greeting "Moin" in northern Germany. I know it translates to hello and I can use it in any day hour, but I am not quite sure, if it is more formal or informal and who can I greet with "Moin!"

Comment: For the sake of completeness *moin* is used in Southern Denmark too, usually spelled with a *j*, *mojn*. Used both formally and informally according to my limited experience.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't say "Guten Moin". :)

Comment: Also for completeness, *moi* (without the *n*) is used as a greeting in parts of the Netherlands (chiefly in the north and east).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the explanation, that *moin* is Frisian and just means *good* and morning/ evening/ whatever time of day is skipped, wich makes the greeting quite generic . (*Moin* is mis-interpreted as somewhow related to *Morgen* by non- Notherners frequently, however.)

From this I would conclude, that it is surely not formal, but neither explicitly informal.  It is misunderstood, however, the further South you go, but in the region of Bremen it is fine.

Surely can canrespond with *moin*, if you are greeted with it.

Comment: That *moin* is derived from Low German *moi* (angenehm, gut, schön) seems to a be widely accepted explanation. But reading [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moin) suggests to me that it nobody really knows it ("wird vielfach angenommen"; "Gegen die Herleitung von Moin aus dem ostfriesisch-niederdeutschen mōj könnte allerdings die Tatsache sprechen, ...").  So it is nothing more than a hypothesis.

Comment: A different widespread theory says *moin* was originally derived from *Morgen* (*morning*). In any case *moin* is certainly used at all times of day.

Answer (score 1):

As guidot♦ already pointed out, it is a word from a dialect or a language from a foreign country bordering Germany.

Therefore, it cannot be considered a formal greeting in business.

If you are in a region where "Moin" is commonly used everywhere ( people regularly use it in conversation), it is certainly appropriate to enter the baker's shop or greet a friend.

When business partners use "Moin", it is also acceptable to use it.

***Why:***
As has already been written here, misunderstandings can arise with people who do not use it themselves. The greeting should be a friendly prelude to a conversation. "Moin" sounds rather cold and clumsy (for people who do not use it themselves because they come from a different region), so I would avoid using it as a start to a conversation with a stranger.